play a video.m3u8 from string instead file [ LibVLCSharp ]
I am using the LibVLCSharp library to play an m3u8 file. (TS encrypted videos)
I want to use a string (text of the same file) instead of m3u8 file to the code for more security.
{In fact, I encrypt the m3u8 file with static key and save it on hard disk. I want to decrypt it in the program and play the m3u8 file without saving decrypted file on hard disk.}
Acceptable code for the library
            LibVLC _libVLC = new LibVLC("");
            _libVLC.SetLogFile("log1.txt");

            videoView1.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);

            Media plist = new Media(_libVLC, "vi/file.m3u8", FromType.FromPath);
            videoView1.MediaPlayer.Play(plist);

The code I want does not work
string s = "#EXTM3U\r\n
            #EXT-X-VERSION:3\r\n
            #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17\r\n
            #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\r\n
            #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD\r\n
            #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=\"key\",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000\r\n
            #EXTINF:16.666667,\r\n
            file0.ts\r\n
            #EXTINF:8.333333,\r\n
            file1.ts\r\n
            #EXTINF:8.333333,\r\n
            file2.ts\r\n
            #EXTINF:9.133333,\r\n
            file3.ts\r\n
            #EXT-X-ENDLIST";

    LibVLC _libVLC = new LibVLC("");
    _libVLC.SetLogFile("log1.txt");

    videoView1.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    MediaInput aa = new StreamMediaInput(stream);

    Media plist = new Media(_libVLC, aa, ""); 
    videoView1.MediaPlayer.Play(plist);

play m3u8 video with LibVLCSharp form a string.

using(var libVLC = new LibVLC())
{
    var media = new Media(libVLC, "vi/file.m3u8", FromType.FromLocation);
    await media.Parse(MediaParseOptions.ParseNetwork);
    using (var mp = new MediaPlayer(media.SubItems.First()))
    {
            var r = mp.Play();
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


Thank you for your answer, but in your code, "vi/file.m3u8" is read from a file, not from a string.

just use the Uri constructor
